# KeyError: after overriding __nonzero__

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python is my first programming language, not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
def __nonzero__():
    if pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([extract[['KA_MONTHLY_VPO']]>= 200]) :
        extract['VALUE_FV'] = (FV285)
    return __bool__()

print (extract['VALUE_FV'])
```

Comment: You should probably drop that and learn some basics first.